# Passing javascript string to std::string prints garbage values

Tags: javascript, c++, dll, electron, ffi

I'm playing with C++ and ElectronJS. I'm trying to pass a Javascript string to c++ dll using **ElectronJS** and **node-ffi**. The rest exposed functions are working fine aside from `GetString`.

Javascript Code:

```
window.onload = function () {
  try {
  
    // Call *.dll with ffi
    let ffi = require('ffi-napi');
        
    // Create funtions
    window.Dll = ffi.Library(".//dll//BasicMathDll.dll", {
      'add': ['float', ['float', 'float']],
      "subtract": ["float", ["float", "float"]],
      "multiply": ["float", ["float", "float"]],
      "divide": ["float", ["float", "float"]],
      "GetString": ["string",["string"]]
    })
    
    console.log("DLL was loaded correctly.");
    
    
    // Call C++ function Hello
    //document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = Dll.Hello()
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('ffi.Library', error);
    document.getElementById('result').value = error;
  }
  
}
```

Wrapper.cpp

```
std::string GetString(std::string a) {

FILE* fp;
fp = fopen("a.txt", "w+");

fprintf(fp, a.c_str());

fclose(fp);

return "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
}
```

Wrapper.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef BASICMATHDLL_EXPORTS
#define BASICMATHDLL_API  __declspec (dllexport)
#else
#define
#define BASICMATHDLL_API __declspec (dllimport)
#endif

#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32)
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORT
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct CWrapper {
    void* cObject;
}CWrapper_T;

CWrapper_T *create();
void destroy(CWrapper_T*);
float CheckTask(CWrapper_T* mObject, float x, float y, char mOperator);

EXPORT float add(float x, float y);
EXPORT float subtract(float x, float y);
EXPORT float multiply(float x, float y);
EXPORT float divide(float x, float y);
EXPORT std::string GetString(std::string);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I am calling the exposed dll function like this:

```
function GetStr(){
    // Call C++ function GetString
    document.getElementById('string').innerHTML = window.Dll.GetString("Lorem ipsum dolor.");
}
```

The text file generated (**a.txt**) contains:
`øã«~S{Säã`

I believe that there is something wrong with character encoding between javascript string and c++ std::string and that's beyond my knowledge for now. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Never having to use JavaScript and C++ together, you shouldn't pass objects such as `std::string` across module boundaries.  A `std::string` is a C++ thing, only known by C++, and even then , can have different internals when using a different C++ compiler or compiler options.  Also, the `std::string` has internal memory management, meaning that the heap being used by `std::string` in one module needs to be the same heap used in the calling module.  Also, that `std::string` is a temporary -- you also have an issue with scope. 
 Find another way to safely pass character data between languages.

Comment: *"pass a Javascript string to c++ dll using **ElectronJS** and **node-ffi**."* -- What does the documentation for those two have to say about the format used for strings on the receiving end? (It's doubtful that the format would be not only C++-specific, but C++-compiler-specific, as `std::string` is.)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Maybe finding another way is good. Even in my code i have wrapped some C++ code to C code because of ABI issues. Could it be the gap was also here.

Comment: @JaMiT that one i need to dig deep. I haven't yet found any specific documentation like that. I'll check further. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried **C style string** which is `const char*` instead of **C++** `std::string` and it worked fine.
Below is the little adjustment i have made.

Wrapper.h

```
EXPORT const char* GetString(const char*);
```

Wrapper.cpp

```
const char* GetString(const char* a) {

FILE* fp;
fp = fopen("a.txt", "w+");

fprintf(fp, a);

fclose(fp);

return "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
}
```

And now my `a.txt` file has a correct value passed from JS.